# Is there a way to get Kotlin function's owner via reflection

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Suppose we have the following functions:

```
class MyClass {
fun myFunction() {}
companion object {
    fun myStaticFunction() {}
}
}

fun myTopLevelFunction() {}
```

When I am debugging thru the following:

```
           val functions = listOf(
            MyClass::myFunction,
            MyClass.Companion::myStaticFunction,
            ::myTopLevelFunction
        )
        functions.forEach {
            val names = (it::class.java).fields.map {
                method -> println(method.name)
            }
```

Intellij can correctly show me in "Evaluate Expression" this information

- owner (MyClass, MyClass.Companion etc.
- whether this is a top level function

But I cannot find a way to do it via reflection. For instance, I cannot figure out how to read function's owner. What am I missing? TIA.

In Intellij I can see functions' owners like this

```
myFunction -> MyClass
myStaticFunction -> MyClass.Companion
myTopLevelFunction -> MyFileNameKt
```

Comment: What do you mean by a function's "owner"?

Comment: @Tenfour04 explained in the question's body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `KFunction` does not provide us with such capability. If you are not afraid of using publicly available utils from `kotlin.jvm.internal` package then you can check if `KFunction` is a `CallableReference` and then use its `owner` property:

```kotlin
functions.forEach {
    if (it is CallableReference) {
        println(it.owner)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest how to pull it - my search came up empty:

https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=kotlin.jvm.internal

Comment: You don't need to add any dependencies, it's in stdlib. Do you get an unresolved reference problem? IntelliJ can't auto-import it?

Comment: thanks a lot this did it!